# Display SVG images using node.js?

Tags: javascript, image, node.js, http, svg

Complete neewbie to node.js.

Do i need to install a plugin/module/mime type to get node.js to display SVG images in browsers?

I've tried using the `<embed>` and `<object>` tags a 'A plugin is needed to display this content'.

```
<embed src="http://aws.cloudfront.net/assets/myimage.svg" type="image/svg+xml" />
```

or

```
<object data="http://aws.cloudfront.net/assets/myimage.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```

Comment: display it on what?  in your browser or through a window opened by node?

Comment: Sorry. Yes. In browsers. (I'll update the question)

Comment: Are you serving the .svg as a static file?  Make sure the mime type is  set to `image/svg+xml`

Comment: did you serving SVG files via nodejs? did you used the correct HTML tag in your page? Check out the guide [SVG In HTML Pages](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_inhtml.asp)

Comment: Yes. Serving the .svg as a static file. I'll update the question with the HTML I'm using.

Comment: Have you tried serving it into a simple `<img>` tag?

Comment: Yep. the `<img>` tag was what i tried first.

Comment: I take it from peoples comments that node.js should do this out of the box?

Comment: Add your node.js code.